# Hosting StyleCop in a Custom Environment

Tags: c#, stylecop

I want to host StyleCop in a Custom Environment, the sample code provided in SDK uses this `foreach(string myProject in this.myProjects)`. `String` doesn't have properties like `Path.GetHashCode()` and `FilesToAnalyze`, does anyone knows what is `this.myProjects`?

```
List<CodeProject> projects = new List<CodeProject>();    

// what is this.myProject?
foreach (string myProject in this.myProjects)
{
     CodeProject project = new CodeProject(
         myProject.Path.GetHashCode(), myProject.Path, configuration);

    // Add each source file to this project.
    foreach (string sourceFilePath in myProject.FilesToAnalyze)
    {
        console.Core.Environment.AddSourceCode(project, sourceFilePath, null);
    }

    projects.Add(project);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the example in the SDK I think `myProject` is just a placeholder to indicate how to construct a `CodeProject` instance.

If you want you can define a class as shown below or keep the root path and files to analyze in a different data structure.

```
public class MyProject
{
    public string Path { get { ... } }

    public IEnumerable<string> FilesToAnalyze { get { ... } }
}
```

Comment: You might be right ... but see the first foreach (string myProject in this.myProjects), this indicates that MyProject is collection of string ....

Comment: @alittlebitofday: As you've already observed, `string` doesn't have a `Path` or `FilesToAnalyze` property. So the example from the SDK won't compile "as is".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just meant to be a pseudocode example. Your best bet it to go to stylecop.codeplex.com and just look at the actual StyleCop code. There are many examples in the code showing how to host StyleCop.